# Is it okay to rewrite a poorly written question of mine?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709071/has-anyone-ever-tried-to-jit-compile-a-macro-language) question. The question was horrible, and I deserved the downvotes and closing of the question.

I believe that I can rewrite the question to be "Would there be any practical benefit from JIT compiling a macro language?". Should I edit my original question, or should I ask a new one?

Comment: What would the new question be?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it would be to ask whether there would be any practical benefit to JIT compiling a macro language.

Comment: You're still in subjective territory.  Is there a question that you want to ask that addresses a practical problem?

Comment: Note that "m4" is a "template/preprocessor" language, which basically means that it is a text transformer.  It doesn't produce machine code; it produces text (source code), so JITting it is a meaningless exercise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant JIT compiling the execution of certain macros, treating them as functions (which they are, in a sense).

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?  It is good that this user is asking advice on being a part of the SO community after they had their question closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't beat yourself up about the question—just because it may not fit for StackOverflow doesn't necessarily mean it's not a good fit for another Stack Exchange site, or the rest of the internet for that matter!

Neither of your questions (both the original and the revised one you proposed in the comments above) really fits the type of questions Stack Overflow is made for—the '[What type of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' help article is a good resource here. Your questions fit the following 'do-not-ask-criteria' fairly clearly:

- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
- you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Again, that doesn't remotely mean it's a bad question (you actually got me thinking about it for a bit), just that it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. So in response to question:

> Should I edit my original question, or should I ask a new one?
>
> ...it would be to ask whether there would be any practical benefit to
>   JIT compiling a macro language.

In this case, the answer is 'neither'.

*However*, if you decide to go on some adventurous endeavor and find the answer for yourself by building a macro language with JIT capabilities—*do* ask if you need any technical help there!